# The connection is broken and recovery is not possible - sql server error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, connectivity, tempdb

I am having the following sql server error, while creating tempDB files.
Any ideas?

[image]

> The connection is broken and recovery is not possible.  The client
>   driver attempted to recover the connection one or more times and all
>   attempts failed.  Increase the value of ConnectRetryCount to increase
>   the number of recovery attempts. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been sorted out.

what it was is that while changing the tempDB file locations I put them in the T: drive and the sql server accounts did not have permissions there.

After I have [copied all permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/218984/22336) from the sql server data folder to the T: drive it all worked fine.

to copy all the folder permissions from  *D:\data* to *T:\tempdb* using [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-6) (*run as administrator*):

```
$Acl = Get-Acl "D:\data"
Set-Acl "T:\tempdb" $Acl
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is an old thread but this was the first hit on Google so I'm going to add my experience here. I was using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise while remote connected to the server.

I was attempting to restore a database from backup WITH REPLACE and RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY. Between the backup and my first transaction log I received the error indicated above. No databases on the server were able to be accessed; all received the same message. I was, however, able to access the other databases by connecting through a local instance of SSMS and it indicated that my intended target database was (Restoring...), as expected.

Turns out, all I had to do on the server instance of SSMS was restart SSMS. All was normal after that.

Comment: That helped.  In my case I only disconnected the DB Server in the Object Explorer and reconnected.  Didn't need to restart SSMS itself.  Thanks for adding your solution

Comment: restarting SSMS works, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue when I was trying to **Deploying a Database to Azure SQL Server**. I tried a few times and I got the same error. I double-check the Azure permissions, Firewall, user and pwd.

What I did to fix it was run SQL Management Studio as **Administrator**. Simple as it.

I believe the problem was some permission to the temporary file to "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp" to create *bacpac* file.

Answer (score -1):

My problem was rather stupid
I opened a query to my already connected server
but as the query was not connected, running a line on it gave me this error
so first of all check if you are connected.