# how to script out all the permissions in a folder using powershell?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, security, configuration, powershell

Using the script below I find out where are the data and log folders:

```
    declare @rc int, 
    @dir nvarchar(4000) 

    declare @data    nvarchar(4000)
    declare @log     nvarchar(4000)
    declare @SQLPath nvarchar(4000)
    declare @Backup  nvarchar(4000)

    exec @rc = master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup',N'SQLPath', @dir output, 'no_output' 
    select @SQLPath = @dir

    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    --For the default data location: 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------

    exec @rc = master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',N'DefaultData', @dir output, 'no_output' 


    if (@dir is null) 
    begin 
    exec @rc = master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup',N'SQLDataRoot', @dir output, 'no_output' 
    select @dir = @dir + N'\Data' 
    end 

    select @data = @dir

    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    --For the default log location: 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    exec @rc = master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',N'DefaultLog', @dir output, 'no_output' 


    select @log = @dir


    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    --For the default Backup location: 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    exec @rc = master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',N'BackupDirectory', @dir output, 'no_output' 


    select @Backup = @dir

    SELECT  
    [data path] =     @data, 
    [log path] =      @log, 
    [sql path] =      @SQLPath, 
    [Backup Folder] = @Backup
```

Then I manually go to that folder and have a look at the permissions sql server (`the sql server services account`) has on that folder.

[image]

I would like to script those permissions so that I can apply them to a new folder.

Using `powershell`, how can I script all those permissions from this folder `let's say folder a:\data` and apply those permissions to `folder b:\data` on the same machine?

Comment: I do not have a ready to use script, but this might help? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/11/22/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-get-add-and-remove-ntfs-permissions/

Comment: You should use ROBOCOPY - `ROBOCOPY <source> <target> /MIR /SEC /SECFIX` https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2008/07/31/robocopy-mir-switch-mirroring-file-permissions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get-Acl worked for me to copy permissions from my dev machine DATA folder to a test folder.

```
$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER01\MSSQL\DATA"
Set-Acl "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\test" $Acl
```

This overwrites the permissions on the new folder, handle with care.

(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johan/2008/10/01/powershell-editing-permissions-on-a-file-or-folder/)

Comment: +1 this worked as a charm for me!!!